# Авторизация и вывод данных в админ панель на Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

Я хочу, чтобы данные из шаблона сохранялись в базу данных, а затем выводились в Админ панель. Для этого я делаю следующее:

---

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=400, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

url.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import login, reg
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',login),
    path('registration/',reg),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import UserForm

def login(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        user = UserForm(request.POST)
        if user.is_valid():
            user.save()
    user = UserForm()
    return render(request,'login/login.html')
def reg(request):
    return render(request,'login/reg.html')
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(User)
```

reg.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compartible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/reg.css' %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text">registration</div>
      <form action="../" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="container-table">
          <div class="table-text">user name<input class="type" type="text"></div>
          <div class="table-text">email adress<input class="type" type="text"></div>
          <div class="table-text">password<input class="type" type="text"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="but"><input type="submit" value="registration" class="button"></div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Однако, после того, как я регистрирую нового пользователя, он не появляется в админ-панели

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы не регистрируете пользователя, а просто рендерите страницу
2. В шаблоне у вас поля прописаны в ручную, без name. Так делать нельзя, потому что django не узнает какие данные пришли, и потому что надо использовать формы, а не изобретать неработающий велосипед. Извиняюсь заранее, если обидел словами.
3. Что за `action="../"` ? Так делать нельзя. Почитайте [django template tags - url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) .

Советую почитать еще [результаты гугла по запросу "django регистрация"](https://ustimov.org/posts/17/). Чтобы понять, откуда там взялись классы почитайте про Generic Views, они не сложные и очень даже удобные

---

Как решить проблему:

1. Использовать django формы для регистрации https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/django_forms
2. Формой регистрации проверять, что форма валидна. Если валидна - сохранять нового юзера (метод saev() формы регистрации. он должен вернуть нового юзера) и перенаправлять на страницу авторизации, либо сразу авторизовать и перенаправлять на главную страницу профиля или куда вам надо.
3. Выводить форму через {{ form }}
4. По view логина - совет. Проверяйте тип запроса. Если POST - то форма отправлена. Смотрите через форму, валидны ли данные. Если да - авторизуете и редиректите пользователя. Если нет, то выводите пустую форму. Вы же всегда выводите пустую форму. Пользователь конечно автризуется, но попадет на ту же страницу, и не поймет что авторизовался